# Get Username Matches ID

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried many ways of getting the username in codeigniter models. that matches the row id. But can not seem to get my model to work.

I have looked at user guide many times all ways get errors.

It shows the row id / user id OK when echo it

**But can not seem to make a model to be able to match username with row id and then echo it.**

**Any suggestion on suitable model function.**

when I click on my edit button it shows up in url `http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-blog/admin/users/edit/1` which works.

Model

// Not return username that matches id.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_user extends CI_Model {

    function getUsername() {
        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->where('user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Controller function.

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('user');

        if ($this->session->userdata('isLogged') == TRUE) {

            return true;

        } else {

            redirect('/');

        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "Users";

        $data['base'] = config_item('HTTP_SERVER');

        $data['isLogged'] = $this->user->isLogged();

        $this->load->model('users/model_user');

        $data['text_enabled'] = "Enabled";
        $data['text_disabled'] = "Disabled";

        $results = $this->model_user->getUsers();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['users'][] = array(
                'user_id'    => $result['user_id'],
                'username'   => $result['username'],
                'edit'       => site_url('users/edit/' . $result['user_id'])
            );

        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/common/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

        return $this->load->view('template/users/users_list', $data);
    }

    function edit($user_id = 0, $user_group_id = 0) {


        $data['title'] = "Users";

        $data['base'] = config_item('HTTP_SERVER');

        $data['isLogged'] = $this->user->isLogged();

        $this->load->model('users/model_user');

        $data['user_id'] = "Current User ID" . " " . $user_id . ":";

        $data['user_group_id'] = "Current User Group ID" . " " . $user_group_id . ":";

        $data['username'] = "Current User Name:" . " " . $this->model_user->getUsername();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/common/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

        return $this->load->view('template/users/users_form', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'where' requires a second argument, which you would pass as an argument to your model function. so something like this in the model

```
class Model_user extends CI_Model {

    function getUsername($id) {
        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

this corresponds to an sql query like 
    SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id = ?

so in the controller just pass the user id in the argument to the model function

```
$data['username'] = "Current User Name:" . " " . $this->model_user->getUsername($user_id);
```

Comment: error now 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: users/users.php

Line Number: 65

Answer (score 0):

I have found best way to get my username to match user id

**On My Model**

```
function getUsername($user_id) {
        if (empty($user_id)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

          $this->db->select('username');
          $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('user');

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1)  {
                $result = $query->result_array();
                return $result[0]['username'];
        } else {
                return FALSE;
        }

     }
```

on Controller function

```
$this->model_user->getUsername($user_id);
```